# How to make Country - Specific Web Site (and contents)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

Now I am developing a small website about **Cricket News** in php. My plan is to present every day cricket news as posts and my goal is to show viewers **their home country's news top most according to their country..!** Currently I have ordered only a .com domain name and planning to order some country coded domains (like .lk, .in, .au, .gb, .sa etc) according to your answers. So my question is this.

I have seen a lot of major websites have their own bunch of cc domains and **sometimes I cannot go their general .com site even I typed it on the browser's address bar.** (I am in Sri Lanka and some websites only show .lk site even I googled or typed their .com names on my address bar..!) I like to include this technique to my website also, but I don't know how. So please help my following questions.

1. How do I detect visitor's **CORRECT COUNTRY**?
2. Do I need any third-party service or add-ons and are there expensive?
3. How do I change web content according to visitor's country?
4. Should I buy all cc domain names or can I use following technique?

   https://www.sample.com/in/index.php

   https://www.sample.com/sa/index.php
5. Finally, If I can use mentioned technique, how I do that?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, too broad. For 1. what if the user is on a proxy? 2. You could try to do a simple whois on the user's IP and/or use some free API that will check the IP. 3. depends you could auto-install a translating service like google (keep in mind just because someone is in a country doesnt mean they speak that language) 4. you could use directorys, subdomains, or buy the TLDs. 5. Don't know..

Comment: You can download databases and use them in your own database to then compare your visitors ip-address with. For example search for the GeoLite Legacy Downloadable Databases, the accuracy is not 100% for sure. You can pay for more reliable sources with a better accuracy.

Comment: I personally use GeoIP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) and works great, I use it to get the country code (us, ar, au, it, ca, mx) and redirect to such folder and if none matches my folders I redirect them to a general-purpose page but, if you wanted to, you can also code something very dynamic and create a `template.php` sort of thing so you can create a new folder and copy the file to that folder as `index.php` and get it to work, but of course this means a lot of thinking in the database and template file(s), etc.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you very much for pointing me some valuable points.! And also your answering method is so easy to understand..! cheers..!

Comment: @Santy Got it Santy..! Thank you very much..!

Comment: @Zeke You have summarized all key points to a great answer. I'll try your link documentation. Thank you very much for your help..!

Comment: @LuckyG Thanks, I hope it helps you somehow. Remember GeoIP is a PECL extension. If you don't own your server, ask your host to install it for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need user IP Address and [IP 2 Location](http://www.geoplugin.net) API. Try the following example with complete solution to detect User's country.

Try

```
$userip  = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

$ip_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$userip));
echo $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
```

**Output**

> US

Comment: Thank you very much..! I will try this and comment my results..!